# Show that two surfaces intersect at the given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces

The given surfaces and point are
$$f(x,y)=xy$$
$$g(x,y)=\frac{3}{4}x^2-2y$$
$$(2,-3,-6)$$
First I made each surface have three variables by subtracting $z$ from both sides. Then I found the gradient of the surfaces
$$f(x,y,z)=\left<y,x,-1\right>$$
$$g(x,y,z)=\left<\frac{3}{2}x, -2y ,-1 \right>$$
Then finding the gradient at the given point
$$f(x,y,z)=\left< 2,-3,-1\right>$$
$$g(x,y,z)=\left<3,6 ,-1 \right>$$
Then I found the cross product of the two and got
$$9i -j+21k$$
But I'm not sure how this shows that the two surfaces intersect.

Comment: The point does not belong to the second surface.

Comment: To check whether two surfaces intersect at given point, just check whether the point belongs to both surfaces? Are $-6 = (2)(-3)$ and $-6 = \frac34(2)^2-2(-3)$ both true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** The surfaces do not intersect at the point in OP because that point does not belong to the second surface. They do, however, have the whole curve $y=3/4x^2/(x+2),z=xy$ in common. In particular , they have the point $(4,2, 8)$ in common. Proving that the surfaces intersect (and not touch) at that point can be done along the line you suggested.